# How to distinghish 2.8 question (and the corresponding rendering settings)?

Tags: discussion

What can we do to understand the subject when the question can be 2.8 (or not) and can be Eevee (or Cycles)?

I think all is said, except that the OP rarely (never) indicate this context.

Previously this was coming by itself: Internal or Cycles. In 2.8 I've not seen any indication about it.

Do you think this is a problem? If yes what can we propose to solve it?

(for information, I don't know which tag to set about it. Version? no, 2.8? no, context?... so 'discussion' will be the good one)

An example : [Weird reflection in glossy material when camera is in front of the object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146089/weird-reflection-in-glossy-material-when-camera-is-in-front-of-the-object)

The OP indicates 2.8 but which rendering system?

Comment: I'd say just ask them in a comment. However in this specific case I doubt the render engine is of relevance.

Comment: I *think* render engine is quite related when the question is about  materials with caustics (transparent / glossy), but anyway not much anyone can do on BSE except for usual "what's your render engine" comment and asking for a blend. Regarding tags - there is "eevee" one instead of "internal" and "cycles" so I think all the same here

Comment: @MrZak, less obvious in this deleted question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146356/let-light-through-solid-object-in-2-8 . Marked as duplicate but was it really a Cycles question?

Comment: Not visible for me since it's deleted, but anyway the general principle stays - if OP didn't take a minute to include useful screenshots (which in 2.8 isn't quite related anymore since engine dropdown isn't visible always) and didn't include engine specifics etc then only with comments

Comment: Aren't there tags for that? Shouldn't we just ask users in comments to add tags to the question (or add them ourselves)?